# Passing a variable scoped to script from a custom JSP tag

Tags: jsp, tags, jsp-tags

Apologies if this is a stupid question and if it's duplicate.

May I please ask how (and if) it's possible to pass a (script scoped) variable from a custom JSP tag `prefix:tag attribute name`

as `<my:example var = '${foo}'> </my:example>`

where `foo` is defined in `<script>`?

`index.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script>
    var foo = "bar";
</script>

<my:example var='${foo}'></my:example> --> I'd not like to pass a constant here. That being said, I believe I am not thinking in the right way of how a variable is passed whose scope is local to the script tag?
</html>
```

`example.tag`

```
<%-- example.tag --%>
<%@ attribute name="var" required="true" rtexprvalue="true"%>
<p>Hello, ${var}! :)</p> --> I'd wish this to be printed as whatever is passed from the custom tag; however, and please correct me if I am wrong, I could not find any resources online that do not pass constants from the custom tag
```

`Expected Output`

```
Hi, bar! :)
```

`Actual Output`

```
Hi, ! :)
```

Please point me to the right direction and help me understand what am I doing wrong here along with how can I improve my thinking on solving problems like these in the future? I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP is evaluated on the server side, while scripts on the client (browser) side. So the `foo` variable won't have any value assigned unless html is generated from the jsp - variable defined in script starts 'existing' only after generated html is sent to the browser and evaluated by it.

So, as far as I know, the short answer for your question is: it's not possible to directly pass a `foo` variable declared inside `<script>` tag to use inside the jsp (on server side)

If you want the output to have value of `foo`, you have either to declare the variable in jsp, or change value of your `<p>` tag using JS. Choice depends wheter you can assign value on the server side, or it should be modifiable on actions on the client side.

While following code snippets may not be complete, they should point you in general direction.

server side (JSP):

```
(...)
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
(...)
<c:set var="foo" value="bar">
```

client side (JS) - here you would have to make some more modifications:

`example.tag` - you can set a `<span>` with an id for your `<p>` tag so you could access it from the script:

```
(...)
<p>Hello, <span id="foo"></span> :)</p>
```

then you can access the `foo` span tag using js:

```
<script>
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.textContent = "bar";
</script>
```

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for your reply! What should I do in the case below?

`<p> <my:example var1="${variable1}" var2="${variable2}" /> </p>`

Comment: @λ13 it's hard to give a definite answer as it all depends on your particular use-case. It looks like you can just scale one of the options from the answer to use 2 vars/spans. Is there a particular reason why you were trying to set var using js and then access it directly inside jsp?

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement infinite scrolling. While scrolling, once I reach the end of the page, I send an AJAX post request and in my java controller I call the database to get few values.

I do multiple things with the values I get from backend and use `<p> <my:example var1="${variable1}" var2="${variable2}" /> </p>` to pass these in a separate `.tag` file `example.tag` (which is pretty large). So, in short, I need to pass the data I get from the database and append to the `p` tag and for that I am passing the data as attributes to `example.tag`

Comment: @λ13 Ok, so you've already passed the values from frontend to the controller using a POST call, and now you are trying to send back new page contents as a jsp? I don't know what framework you use in the backend, but you have to add the values generated by controller to model passed into the jsp, and than you should be able to access them in it.
I think it would be best if you include the AJAX call and relevant controller parts in the question, or maybe even it would be better to create new one as a followup question